# Postman passed values get into servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-kafka, postman

I am passing some values (like firstname, lastname, email, phone) from postman doPost request(as JSON) at Url like below to java TestServlet
https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:yyyy/xyz/TestServlet

I like to retrieve these values in servlet and save to topic on kafka producer.

How to retrieve postman passed values inside servlet and later store to producer

Comment: Do you have any code so far that simply prints the data that was sent to the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Postman is an implementation detail. You could use any HTTP client to send a request to the servlet.

Inside your doPost method body, you'd parse the request body content as JSON, then you'd construct (or reference) a KafkaProducer instance, then build a new ProducerRecord, and send it